# Who is the voice actor of Grataa in Star Wars: the Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-the-old-republic

### Introduction

Let me first say that I am not sure that this question is great for this SE, but seeing as I found none more suitable, I'm posting it here.

In Star Wars: the Old Republic, by Bioware, there is a character by the name of [Grataa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grataa): he's a representative for the Great Hunt in the Bounty Hunter storyline.

#### A screenshot of the character:

[image: Picture of Grataa]

### Question

My question is simple to ask, but perhaps harder to answer: **Who is the voice actor for this character?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was speculated [as early as 2012 on *The Old Republic* community forum](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=2131178&postcount=15) that Graata was voiced by [Tom Kane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Kane):

> If you're talking about the Kaleesh Grataa from Hutta, that's Tom Kane.

This was recently confirmed on [*The Old Republic*'s IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1320395/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) (emphasis mine):

> **Tom Kane:** M1-4X / Commander Narlock / A-4P0 / AR-G0 / CB-08-4 / Captain Trezin / Commander Vorten Fett / Commander Yajak / Doctor Tabo / General Ando / **Grataa** / Hallam Organa / Jedi Knight Xerender / Master Sulan / Master Vandar Tokare / ODX-9 / PO-12 / Security Chief / Tazonthe Ghon (voice)

Comment: Thank you, that seems as legit a source as we'll get, I think.

Comment: On another matter. Hasn't Bounty Hunter been in TOR since it's launch in 2011?

Comment: @GunnarSödergren Sorry, I misread your post. I don't actually play TOR, but I heard they recently released a new expansion; I got myself confused. You're right; they've been around since the beginning